# Gradle Sync failed could not find constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1

Tags: java, android, xml

> **Error** Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1. I have tried updating my sdk tools (constraint layout for Android &, solve for Constraint Layout) to solve this issue, but I can't see "1.0.0-alpha1" version in options so I downloaded "1.0.0" version and gradle it but it again shows error.

Comment: It's no longer alpha, so you need to upgrade. See the documentation?
 https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project

Comment: i again get error, i think i have done something wrong, iam new in android studio, can u plz. guide me with step by step press. i"ll very thankful to u.

Comment: @user8794409: you'll find that if you use all-lower-case writing and txtspk you will probably get more downvotes. Please try to use the correct case and spellings, so your writing is clearer for your readers.

Comment: The error is probably because you did not add the Google repository, as mentioned in the documentation. Also, you accepted the answer which says exactly what the documentation does, so it's not clear what issue you're having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

which is new version of constraint layout.

Error is due to lint will give error to add new latest version of this layout. Current latest version is '1.1.0-beta3' so try to add it or choose option above, it will works. Use of Old version is fine, but we should use current stable version. since some kind of functionality might not there in old versions..